# Angular Value is null under ngOint event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having an issue accessing a variable value after it was set in the ngOint event, the value of val is available within function GetApps but it is not available under process function

**TS**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
val:any;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.GetApps();
 this.process()
}

  GetApps() {
         this._srvc.getApps()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
             this.val = data;
            console.log(this.val);
            },
            error => this.showMessage('some error: ' + <any>error, 1));
    }

   this.process()
   {
     console.log(val) //is undefined
   }


}
```

Comment: `subscribe(.....)` part is asynchronous

Comment: so how do I fix the issue

Comment: There's some typos on the code, can you update it?

Comment: call it within subscribe

Comment: i am aware of this solution..I have a complex logic and need another way

Answer (score 3):

You don't set `val` in the `GetApps` function. You set it in the callback function you pass to `subscribe`.

`getApps` runs asynchronously, and when the `process` function is called, the callback function was not run yet.

You could call the `process` function inside the callback function.

Comment: yes, this will work for simple example...I simplified my code....it is not possible to call process inside the getApps..is there another way?

Comment: @rgoal there is no other way. The way I look at it is that anything in the typescript fires automatically except for `subscribes`. I always assume subscribes fire 10 seconds after I call them. so if something is dependent on the subscribe value, you will have to find a away to call it within the subscribe or have some sort of change detection. if you need it in html, you may need to use a `*ngIf`

Answer (score 1):

@sloth's answer is correct. But if you want to access asynchronous code in a synchronous manner, you might consider using async/await.

1. Transform your observable into a promise so it can be awaited on
2. Transform your `GetApps` and init into an asynchronous function to await Promises in it
3. Await the result and call other functions synchronously

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  val:any;

  async ngOnInit() { // transform this into an async function
    try {            // handle errors in synchronous try-catch code
      const val = await this.GetApps();
      this.process(val);  // do something

    } catch(error) {
      this.showMessage('some error: ' + <any>error, 1)
    }
  }

  async GetApps() { // transform this into an async function
    return this._srvc.getApps().toPromise(); // transform this into a Promise
  }

  this.process(val: any) {
    console.log(val) // is not undefined!
  }

}
```

What happens here is that `await this.GetApps()` will block the function execution until the promise is resolved.

Comment: that will work...also I came up with another way...see my answer at the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

```
val:any = null;
```

.subscribe is asynchronous, hence this._srvc.getApps() response might not available while your this.process() get executed. Thats why it is showing that error. To avoid you can always initialize the variable with the appropriate type. That's the aim of TS

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another way to resolve this issue, so If you need to access a variable within ngOnint and you don't want to call process method within subscribe GetApp , you can use global val

**1) added it to the app.component inside the constructor**

```
val:any;
 constructor(private _param: AppParamasService, private _service: AppComponentService) {
 this._srvc.getApps()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
             this.val = data;
             this._param.SetAppValSource(this.val);
            },
            error => this.showMessage('some error: ' + <any>error, 1));
```

**2) app-params.service (shared service)**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class AppParamasService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    public appVal: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    SetAppValSource(apps: any) {
        this.appVal.next(apps);
    }
```

**3) Finally inside SomeCompoent constructor Class**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
val:any;
      constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService){

        _appParams.appVal.subscribe((val) => {
            this.val = val;

        });
       }
 ngOnInit() {
        this.process()
      }

    this.process()
   {
     console.log(val) value is recognized 
   }

}
```